# Spark 2.x dataframe read from using fixed schema

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.2 to do some data integration stuff. I have a question in terms of loading data in json format.

Suppose we have initialized `SparkSession` as `ss`.

I use the following way to load data in json format (one json per line):

```
val df = ss.read.json(path_to_the_json_file)
```

However, what I want is to fix a schema when loading the json data, I know there is way, which is to specify a schema when reading the json:

```
val df = ss.read.schema(schema).json(path_to_json_file)
```

In terms of the schema, I define it using `case class`:

```
case class MySchema(id: String, name: String, departmentId: Int)
val schema = Encoders.product[MySchema].schema
```

However, I have two special cases:

1. I do not want to have all fields in the original json, I only want to have the fields that I specified in the case class.
2. Not every json have every field I specified in the case class, in which case, I would like that the correponding columns will be filled with `null`.

I tried the way above, but it turns out that all records become `null` in the DataFrame.

Could anyone give some hint? Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `read.json(path).as[MySchema]`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your reply, if I use the above way, it will raise analysis exception, saying that some field can not to cast to, say, ```int```, I know this may be another quesiton :). However, by specifying the schema followed by ```read``` seems to handle the type problem.

Comment: I feel like I've typically seen code handle this situation reading a file as plain text, then using the from_json UDF to apply filtering and casting after the fact. From there, you can cast to a case class

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks cricket, your comment works well. In my case, there is a problem, the json data is not the valid one, all the values are simply ```string```, any hint to parse this kind of json data?

Comment: If everything is a string, and not valid JSON objects, then you again shouldn't be using `read.json` or calling your data files as JSON extension. You're left basically with regex or other string functions rather than `from_json`

Comment: @cricket_007 got it, I will figure it out, thanks again!